# bookmarkManagerPrivate permissions for Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm implementing my own bookmarks extensions for chrome that syncs them with firebase, allows tagging and provide a web interface for accessing bookmarks. I want to override the default Bookmarks Manager page, but with the latest version of Chrome some APIs seem not to be available anymore - APIs for import/export bookmarks.

I took a look at the default [Bookmarks Manager](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium.git;a=blob;f=chrome/browser/resources/bookmark_manager/manifest.json;h=29d2306f77c030fd0404b8b5f9a115253f71e5c4;hb=HEAD) and noticed that it defines some permissions that are not available for myself to use:

```
"permissions":[
    "bookmarks",
    "bookmarkManagerPrivate",
    "metricsPrivate",
    "systemPrivate",
    "tabs",
    "chrome://favicon/",
    "chrome://resources/"
]
```

As you can see above, the manifest file defines `bookmarkManagerPrivate` permissions.

Does anyone know something about these new permissions that are not documented anywhere?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It may be possible with the available APIs.

Comment: So, i'm trying to replace completely the default bookmarks manager page.  if i override default page, i have to provide an options for import/export bookmarks somehow, but there are no apis for that in the lastest version of chrome, as these apis are behind the bookmarkmanagerprivate permissions.

Of course i can provide an options page instead overriding default bookmarks page ...

Answer (score 1):

The API for exporting and importing bookmarks are indeed not available from the extensions. Luckily, the format of the exported is well known: it's an HTML file, that follows the `NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1` doctype. This doctype is the exact same format used by Firefox and Internet Explorer.

I've found this [page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that explains how to format such a page.

A final note: an extension can only write a file in a sandboxed part of the user's filesystem (via the [`window.webkitRequestFileSystem` API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/)), so you won't be able to provide a dialog box to select where to export that file.